# Require seatpost size of Dahon Vitesse D7

Tags: seatpost

I have a Dahon Vitesse D7.. Have lost the seat post. Can you let me know what is the size of the seatpost  will fit to the mentioned model

Comment: You need to measure the place where the post goes.  Or better, find a post that fits (even if the wrong style) and measure that.  There are too many different post sizes to give a number out of the air.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a bike shop and get it measured.

They'll have some seatpost measuring tool like this:
[image]

You basically stick it into the seat tube and it tells you what size seatpost you need.

Alternatively, you could use a vernier caliper to measure the seat tube diameter on the inside (this is key!).

Note that the seat tube diameter is only one dimension; you also need to know what length tube you need. Most seatposts have the same clamp type as well, but you may want to get one with extra fore/aft adjustment or whatever. So, going to a shop and buying one isn't a bad idea if you don't know what you need.